# Is it possible to make something like OSX Services for linux, by leveraging pipes?

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ipc

I was reading the concept of OSX Services and it seemed very cool to me to have utilities like Dictionary, highlight-text-and-open-in-browser and a million other services that provide functionality based on what the user is currently doing.

I have heard it mention that this mechanism is more similar to how [pipes](http://www.linfo.org/pipe.html) work in *nix, rather than background services/daemons. For e.g. , when you highlight text on OSX and select spell-check, it is effectively piping the text (using maybe the Pasteboard) to the dictionary program and returning output.

Let us assume that I have a very resource constrained machine, which means I cant have a zillion background services running - would this (Services/Pasteboard) based approach be more efficient ?

Is there anything similar in Linux ? More precisely, a mechanism to allow me to register my pip services and allow several program to call them. Also, shell pipes may not have strong secuirty built in (conceivably a key-management Service would be affected by this.)

For example, how would you implement a spell-check Service (using a pipe, not a daemon) that constantly checks for spelling mistakes.

Edit: another [good read](http://rixstep.com/2/2/20081231,00.shtml) about how OSX Services are not ideal and about their NextStep origins.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that this is "similar to pipes" is an oversimplification written for consumption by non-technical people. It is, in fact, very little like pipes other than the fact that data is being passed around.

[Deskbar-Applet](http://projects.gnome.org/deskbar-applet/) has a mechanism for getting the current selection, if you want to replicate that functionality.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - could you highlight why it is NOT like pipes ? For example, I can conceptually model a JPEG image based service to be 'cat img.jpeg | my_prog'. 
Is it the Pasteboard that is different (superior?)

Basically, I am trying to understand which of the operating-system's message passing paradigms (that I learned in school), does this leverage:
named pipes, shell pipes, RPC, etc. 

What I want is more generic than Deskbar-applet - basically a framework to implement OSX-like services in Linux (rather than background daemons)

Comment: A 30-second search in Google find that what OS X calls a "pasteboard" everyone else calls a "clipboard". "Piping" is a specific mechanism whereby a FD of one process is connected to a FD of another process. Piping is ephemeral binary data only, whereas a clipboard persists not only data, but also a small amount of metadata.